# Estimate of function with log and square root

Tags: inequality, asymptotics

Let $$f(n)=\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{\log n}{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n\log n}}$$ for all real numbers $n>1$. Using the approximation  $1+x\leq e^x$, we know that $f(n)\leq e^{-\sqrt{\frac{\log n}{n}}\cdot\sqrt{n\log n}}=e^{-\log n}=1/n.$

Is it also true that there exists a constant $c>0$ for which $f(n)>c/n$ for all sufficiently large $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can show

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}nf(n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{\ln n}{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n\ln n}}=1.$$

Then following the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the limit, for all $\,c\neq 1$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $|nf(n)-1|<|c-1|$, which places both an upper bound and a lower bound on the coefficient of $\,1/n$.